# Bootstrap 3 - Disable control but enable style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How could I set a control (input text) disabled but change the style to appear as enabled? I mean, instead of showing the control in gray, showing it in white?

Comment: You could write some CSS to override the Bootstrap disabled styles with the Bootstrap enabled styles.

Comment: I tried but with not sucess :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.bootply.com/125688

```
.form-control[disabled] {
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: LOL I never thought it in a sample way, I just tried to force it with javascript